# How can I change my image src tags from absolute to relative urls on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress site, I need a way to change the previously used image url's from absolute to relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked quite a few times with the below little program to search and replace url's in Wordpress databases.

Before you start, create a backup first. I use [All-in-One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) for this as it's easy to use and it can restore a database or even an entire WordPress site.

After that add [Database Search and Replace Script in PHP](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to your WordPress install and follow the instructions as pointed out on their site to replace your URLs.

You can do a test-run to see if it works and which items will be changed.

Good luck.